# How can I distinguish between an open tag and a closed tag in the findPrevious function in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

I want to find if a searched item is contained within a table.  I use the following code:

```
tableprevious = foundtext.findPrevious('table')
```

However, this code will refer to either

```
<table> or </table>
```

and doesn't make it possible to distinguish if the foundtext is already in a table.  Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't `foundPrevious()` return `<table>...</table>`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `findParent()` method.  If an item is contained in a table, it will have a table tag as an ancestor.  Example:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = '<table><tr><td><b>In table</b></td></tr></table><b>Not in table</b>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
items = soup('b')
for item in items:
    if item.findParent('table'):
        print item
```

This outputs:

```
<b>In table</b>
```